# Android calling custom alertdialog class

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

Here my custom dialogalertdialog class. I want to create custom dialog and i call every activity but i got the some errors. i could not fix it. I dont know how can i fix it.

```
public class AlertForSelection extends AlertDialog {
private Context context;
private List<UpperCategory> lstUpper;
private int id;
private LinearLayout lnrList;
private String name;

public AlertForSelection(Context context, List<UpperCategory> lstUpper) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    this.lstUpper = lstUpper;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.alert_for_selection_view);
    this.lnrList = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lnrList);
    this.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
  }
}
```

here i called with button click.

```
final AlertForSelection alertForSelection = new
AlertForSelection(getApplicationContext(), listUpperCategory);
alertForSelection.show();
```

this is error

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:769)
                                                                              at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:356)
                                                                              at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:94)
                                                                              at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:330)
                                                                              at com.example.samcro.petshop.Activities.NewActivity.BtnUpCategory_Click(NewActivity.java:80)
                                                                              at com.example.samcro.petshop.Activities.NewActivity.access$000(NewActivity.java:24)
                                                                              at com.example.samcro.petshop.Activities.NewActivity$1.onClick(NewActivity.java:56)
                                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
                                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24774)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6518)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: dont used getapplicationcontext  ,beacause the dialog in activit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using getApplicationContext() as Context for the dialog like this

```
AlertForSelection alertForSelection = new AlertForSelection(getApplicationContext(), listUpperCategory);
```

then use YourActivityName.this

```
AlertForSelection alertForSelection = new AlertForSelection(YourActivityName.this, listUpperCategory);
```

Answer (score 4):

you can't use the "getApplicationContext() " to new a AlertDialog , you should attach a activity context to new a AlertDialog,because

```
    Dialog(@NonNull Context context, @StyleRes int themeResId, boolean createContextThemeWrapper) {
    // something not important
    mWindowManager = (WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

    final Window w = new PhoneWindow(mContext);
    mWindow = w;
    w.setCallback(this);
    w.setOnWindowDismissedCallback(this);
    w.setWindowManager(mWindowManager, null, null);
    w.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    mListenersHandler = new ListenersHandler(this);
  }
```

here the new Dialog() function will use the context to new mWindowManager, when u use show()

```
 public void show() {
    // something not important
    mDecor = mWindow.getDecorView();

    WindowManager.LayoutParams l = mWindow.getAttributes();
    if ((l.softInputMode
            & WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_IS_FORWARD_NAVIGATION) == 0) {
        WindowManager.LayoutParams nl = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        nl.copyFrom(l);
        nl.softInputMode |=
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_IS_FORWARD_NAVIGATION;
        l = nl;
    }

    try {
        mWindowManager.addView(mDecor, l);
        mShowing = true;

        sendShowMessage();
    } finally {
    }
}
```

here mWindowManager needs addView ,but if the context is applicationContext, the token of mWindowManager will be null. if the context is activity, activity will bind its token to mWindowManager, it can run well.